# Salesforce reports: How to concatenate distinct values of a field when grouping data in a report?

Tags: reporting

I have a report that displays revenue that is grouped by account.

On each row, I would like to display the concatenated *distinct* values for all of the revenue types.

e.g. Account 1 revenue line 1 has type: 'Standard'
     Account 1 revenue line 2 has type: 'Parent'

I would like the 'types' field in the report row for Account 1 to read 'Standard, Parent'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The report data you are looking for is not possible through reports.

You can do a trick. Create a multi-select picklist on Account object which will contain all revenue type values.

When new revenue type is added, updated or deleted, you will update the picklist values on the Account.

Later, create a report on Account with this picklist.

This is just a thought.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Thanks @Santanu Boral.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) and the “Concatenate Distinct” function.

The big downside is that you need to define your filter criteria for revenue lines upfront. But if you want to capture all of the revenue lines for a particular account, this is probably the easiest way to do it.